# How to set Struts2 dropdown list value, using an iterator variable

Tags: html, jsp, select, struts2, ognl

I'm trying set a drop-down selected  within an struts iterator, and it's having trouble evaluating the index variable, resulting drop-down not getting selected.

```
<s:select list = "itemTypeList" 
       listKey = "itemId" 
     listValue = "description" 
     headerKey = "-1" 
   headerValue = "" 
         value = "%{IteratorList[%{#status.index}].itemBase.{itemId}}" 
/>
```

I found hard-coding the index in the value makes it evaluate correctly.
    `value ="%{IteratorList[0].itemBase.{itemId}}" />`

How can I get the index to evaluate? Any Help is appreciated!

Background info on setup - user is first able to filter an item list in the jsp and then add a new list item which uses the prior filtered options, to set an individual drop-down associated with the list item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't nest `%{}`, and you don't need to. The following should be enough:

```
<s:select list = "itemTypeList" 
       listKey = "itemId" 
     listValue = "description" 
     headerKey = "-1" 
   headerValue = "" 
         value = "%{IteratorList[#status.index].itemBase.{itemId}}" 
/>
```

Comment: Thanks, I made the change and confirmed it was working.